# Android send PHP post and NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: php, android, post

Hi i have two question:

1 I want send post php, for example with Android i send:

```
        URL url = new URL("mysite.php");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());

        ps.print("user=user");
        ps.print("&passw=pass");
        ps.print("&value1"="+1);
        ps.print("&value2"="+2);
        con.getInputStream();
        ps.close();
```

Now this is mysite.php where i reiceive post request:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$val1 = $_POST['value1'];
$val2 = $_POST['value2'];

$val3 = $_POST['value3'];
```

In the java code i have only send value1 and value2, but mysite.php requires three variables value1, value2 and value3, when i will send post request without value3, in value3 what's inside? Value3 will contain null value right?

2 I have try to send post request with android, i have create class:

```
public class SendPostEGet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

private HashMap<String, String> lista_eventi;

public SendPostEGet(HashMap<String, String> lista_eventi){

    this.lista_eventi = lista_eventi;

}

public void esegui(){

    doInBackground("");

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    try{

        URL url = new URL("http://mysite.php");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());

        ps.print("user=user");
        ps.print("&passw=passw");

        Iterator<String> it = lista_eventi.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){

            String key = it.next();
            if(lista_eventi.get(key).equals("true")){

                ps.print("&"+key+"="+1);

            }else{

                ps.print("&"+key+"="+0);

            }


        }


        con.getInputStream();


        ps.close();


    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    return null;
}
}
```

But i have exception:

```
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
....
....
....
```

Why i have this exception?

Comment: Response from server is: NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(40)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling doInBackground() manually. So it will throw an exception. Call SendPostEGet.execute() instead of calling doInBackground().

```
   public void esegui(){
    //doInBackground("");//remove this
    SendPostEGet.execute()//add this
  }
```

Comment: for the first question?

Comment: for second question